# How do you extend a Windows Workflow Receive Activity to put objects onto the context for downstream activities to use?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am working on many workflows for a project I am on.  In all of the work flows, when we execute the Receive Message activity we need to take some info from the message, do a DB query and then use the resulting (POCO) results in **all** of the following activities.  What I am looking for in thsi question is a way to load my data record into a POCO then set it on the workflow's context so it is available to all activities downstream.

Some examples I have found state there is a Properties property on StateActivity only I am not finding it.  It is almost like the class does not allow Properties anymore.  I am looking at this SO question:  [Accessing Arguments, Workflow Variables from custom activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857388/accessing-arguments-workflow-variables-from-custom-activities)

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  I don't particularly want to set it as an OutArgument and then consume it everywhere as an InArgument.

I am working with WWF 4.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the context.Properties is correct way of doing this. Note that the Properties collection is not part of a StateActivity but of the execution context passed to a CodeActivity or a NativeActivity.

Take a look at the [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2009/12/20/workflow-scopes-and-execution-properties.aspx) mentioned in the other answers notes.

Comment: FYI:  I switched to basing my classes on the NativeActivity as it is available here.  It is not available if you use the CodeActivity.